# Create queues in IBM MQ (docker compose )

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, ibm-mq

I'm developing a Spring Boot app which is using IBM MQ. I want all of that to be configured in the docker compose. But the problem is that in the app there are used custom queues that were created from the UI in the browser, example of `application.yml` file:

```
...
ibm:
  mq:
    queues:
      first: QUEUE1
      second: QUEUE2
```

How do I create these queues on the startup now when I'm I want to run it from the docker compose file? When I was running ibm mq manually I was using command like this:

```
docker run --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 --detach ibmcom/mq:latest
```

And now I'm almost doing the same but in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
...
 ibm-mq:
    image: 'ibmcom/mq:latest'
    container_name: ibm-mq
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
      - "9443:9443"
    environment:
      - LICENSE = accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME = QM1
```

Is there any environment variables to create custom queues or how do I do that? I didn't find any solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this information: [Customizing the queue manager configuration](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/9.2.3/docs/usage.md#customizing-the-queue-manager-configuration), you can create a MQSC file named `20-config.mqsc` with some config options that will be run when your queue manager is created. Just put it into the /etc/mqm directory on the image.

So, create your `20-config.mqsc` file like this:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(QUEUE1) REPLACE
DEFINE QLOCAL(QUEUE2) REPLACE
```

And map it to your docker-compose.yml as a volume like this:

```
  ibmmq:
    image: ibmcom/mq
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
      - "9443:9443"
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
    volumes:
      - <your 20-config.mqsc file path>:/etc/mqm/20-config.mqsc
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Chapter [Customizing the queue manager configuration](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/9.2.3/docs/usage.md#customizing-the-queue-manager-configuration) describes the options:

> You can customize the configuration in several ways:
>
> 1. For getting started, you can use the default developer configuration, which is available out-of-the-box for the MQ Advanced for Developers image
> 2. By creating your own image and adding your own MQSC file into the /etc/mqm directory on the image. This file will be run when your queue manager is created.
> 3. By using remote MQ administration, via an MQ command server, the MQ HTTP APIs, or using a tool such as the MQ web console or MQ Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but not completely answers my question (how do I add a config file to docker-compose now?)

Answer (score -1):

```
version: '3'

services:
  mq:
    image: icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest
    ports:
      - "1414:1414"
      - "9443:9443"
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
      - MQ_APP_PASSWORD=passw0rd
      - MQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=passw0rd
    volumes:
      - ./mqdata:/mnt/mqm
```

Comment: How did this answer the original question,  does this somehow create custom queues as they asked? The already accepted answer provide a solution.