# In docker, cannot execute script to manage ibm mq queues when lauching container

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose, ibm-mq

I have a dockerfile that is based on an IBM MQ homemade image (I don't have its sources but its a linux distro).

I want to run the image pass some scripts and keep it runing as daemon.

But each time I try to pass some commands for mq such as :

`echo "DEFINE QLOCAL(TEST_01.TEST.SOMETHING.DEV)" | runmqsc TEST`

nothing happen.

I have tried

`RUN echo "DEFINE QLOCAL(TEST_01.TEST.SOMETHING.DEV)" | runmqsc TEST`

then

`ENTRYPOINT ["echo \"DEFINE QLOCAL(TEST_01.TEST.SOMETHING.DEV)\" | runmqsc TEST"]`

or in my docker-compose file :

`entrypoint: ["myscript.sh"]`
where myscript contain the previous bash script
also tried creating a second container depending on my first one :

```
    mqsetup:
      image: myimage
      depends_on:
        - mq
      restart: "no"
      entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "sleep 10 && echo \"DEFINE QLOCAL(TEST_01.TEST.SOMETHING.DEV)\" | runmqsc TEST"]
```

also tried to use the command method :

```
command:
  - myscript.sh
```

nothing works.

But if I exec into the container :

`docker-compose exec mq /bin/bash`

and then execute my script :

`echo "DEFINE QLOCAL(TEST_01.TEST.SOMETHING.DEV)" | runmqsc TEST`

my queue is created onto my queue manager TEST...

To be fairly honnest I am a bit lost, I know that my script is runned because I debuged it with some touch and echo to know if something happen...

At first I tought that it was too soon to paste the script but that's not it (tried to wait 5 minutes with `sleep 5m` before asking for launching the script but with no luck, and if I try to launch quicker than 5 min but by hand in exec mode, it works well...)

Comment: [Create queues in IBM MQ (docker compose )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733819/create-queues-in-ibm-mq-docker-compose) seems to have a recipe for doing this, involving mounting an initialization file into `/etc/mqm` in the container; does that setup work for you?  You can't really do this in the Dockerfile or in an entrypoint script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the source of the image, I can only guess on what is occurring.

The image by default will be starting up MQ, and your attempts at running runmqsc are interfering with that. You need to ensure that that script is allowed to run, and has had time to start up all its services, which will take longer than 2 seconds, before you execute your runmqsc command. After you execute your runmqsc you will need a no-op instruction that will keep the container running.

If you were making use of `icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest` then you could add `.mqsc` to `/etc/mqm` as suggested in the link provided by @David Maze

What I think you are going have to do is add something like: (where `runmqdevserver` is the script that the current image runs.)

```
entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
command:
- |
     runmqdevserver
     sleep 120  
     echo \"DEFINE QLOCAL(TEST_01.TEST.SOMETHING.DEV)\" | runmqsc TEST
     tail -f /dev/null
```

to your DockerFile.

By the way if `runmqdevserver` is what your image runs, then you could copy your mqsc script into /etc/mqm before running `runmqdevserver` as per the comment by David Maze.